# How to call outside function in filter for RDD data

Tags: apache-spark, filter

Now I know for dataFrame, we could use udf, but currently I am handling RDD, data. Except to use on top function, how can I define a method used by filter in all methods in the class

```
   def date_filer_help(date1, date2):
        date1_arr = date1.split("-")
        date2_arr = date2.split("-")
        for i in range(len(date1_arr)):
            if int(date1_arr[i]) < int(date2_arr[i]):
                return True
            elif int(date1_arr[i]) > int(date2_arr[i]):
                return False
        return True

    def date_filter(prev_date, date, end_date):
        return date_filer_help(prev_date, date) and date_filer_help(date, end_date)


rdd = sc.textFile(action_file).map(lambda x: x.split(','))\
    .filter(lambda x: date_filter("0000-00-00", x[0], "2016-06-30"))
```

I want to write date_filter as static in this class or other classes.Otherwise, in each method, I need to redefine two helps as above again and again.  But it does not work if I run in cluster, how should I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
class DataFilter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sc = SparkContext()

    @staticmethod
    def date_filer_help(date1, date2):
        return date1 <= date2

    @staticmethod
    def date_filter(prev_date, date, end_date):
        return DataFilter.date_filer_help(prev_date, date) and DataFilter.date_filer_help(date, end_date)

    def run(self):
        rdd = self.sc.parallelize(
            map(lambda x: ((datetime.date(2016, 6, 25) + datetime.timedelta(x)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), x), range(10)))
        result = rdd.filter(lambda x: DataFilter.date_filter("0000-00-00", x[0], "2016-06-30"))
        return result.collect()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(DataFilter().run())
```

Comment: Now I realize , it is because I run the main in another file and did not sc.addFile.